# How to get my laptop keyboard lights to stay on? (Acer Aspire E-15)

Tags: keyboard, laptop, acer, keyboard-backlight

I want to know how to get my built in laptop keyboard key lights to stay on all the time.

right now, when i enable my keyboard lights (Fn + F9) it only stays on for about 30 seconds after I type anything before it automatically shuts off. sometimes i like working in the dark, and would like them to somehow be toggled on continuously.

any xset terminal commands dont seem to do anything (xset led), and there isnt anything under system settings.

laptop: Aspire-E5-575G

any help will be appreciated, even a point in the right direction!